# How to Find XML and API for Live Cricket Score?

Tags: xml, api

I want to make an app for iPhone and Android
which I want to show live cricket scores. 
Is there any site that can provide API and rss/xml feed for live scores?

Comment: Litzscore provides REST based API for Live Cricket and Stats. You can read more here https://developers.litzscore.com/. It must be easy to use.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one from ESPNCricinfo - 
http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml

Comment: Can i use cricinfo live scores in my android app, i mean is it free? or i need to pay? Or, does Google Play accepts this if i will make an app that shows live scores by fetching information from cricinfo?

Comment: send an email to cricinfo team

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help: Cric API http://www.cricapi.com/

Comment: Yahoo pipes defunct